# Application Cache manifest file errors with Windows/NTLM authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, offline-caching, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

How are browsers implementing requests for Application Cache manifest files and is it different from how other files are requested?

I ask because I'm seeing behavior I wouldn't expect when using Windows/NTLM authentication in IIS 7. The situation is that I have a site with a manifest file defined. With anonymous authentication, everything works as expected -- the site loads and is available offline.

When I disable anonymous and enable Windows authentication, the site will load fine after authenticating, but I will see an error in the console (in Chrome or on an iPad 2) that says the manifest file could not be fetched.

On the iPad, the error is that the Application Cache file could not be fetched. In Chrome, the specific error is "Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (401)." I can see the 401 response code in the web server logs in both instances.

Why this behavior seems unexpected is requests for all other resources (CSS, JavaScript, images) all work as expected. Also, I can browse to my .appcache file and it loads.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Has anyone else run into this and found a solution?

Comment: Also experiencing the same problem on Apache, where I have HTTP Basic Authentication turned on via .htaccess for the directory containing the app. It seems Chrome is not passing along the Authorization header with the credentials when making the request for the app cache manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I'm also having this problem.

As my site makes AJAX requests, once the page has loaded I am asked for credentials for the request to take place. Once this has happened, running `applicationCache.update()` causes the application cache to update correctly.

Therefore, as a work around, perhaps try making an AJAX request to something so that the user is prompted for credentials, then call `applicationCache.update()`.

Answer (score 0):

i have also run into this problem. Exactly as you described, but i am using basic auth on Apache. I am going to try making the the mainfest file public.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but i had the exact same problem which led me here.

my setup is:
server - IIS8
authentication - windows
anonymous authentication - enabled (did this so i could get my dynamic manifest to be fetched regardless of authentication, i had to then decorate all other controllers with `[Authorize]`)

With the above setup the application would cache properly however when loading from the cache, if there was an update to the manifest certain sections were not fetching (such as authorized content) because the user was not "logged in" and hence making the whole update even fail.

My solution was to add in an ajax call to an authorized resource, this way when the user was online they would be prompted to log in meaning that the next time the cache was updated they were authorized again.